# Query for all month when i use drop down, it calls/display value from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

```
<tr>
    <td class="header">No</td>
    <td class="header">Day</td>
    <td class="header">Date</td>
    <td class="header">SGP4D Result</td>
</tr>
<?php
    require 'dbs/connection.php';

    if(!isset($_POST['searchBtn'])) {
        /* Display records for current month */

        /* Prepare and Execute Query for current month */
        $searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_4d WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_result, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m');";
        $sqlResult = mysql_query($searchQuery);

        if (mysql_num_rows($sqlResult)>0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlResult)) {
               echo "<tr>
                        <td class='content'>" . $row['4d_id'] . "</td>
                        <td class='content'>" . date('l', strtotime($row['date_result'])) . "</td>
                        <td class='content'>" . $row['date_result'] . "</td>
                        <td class='content'>" . $row['4d_result'] . "</td>
                    </tr>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        /* Display records for selected month */

        /* Prepare and Execute Query for current month */
        // $searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_4d WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_result, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m');";
        // $sqlResult = mysql_query($searchQuery);
    }
?>
```

Can you please help me to rearrange this code which runs for the current month only. Any other ideas because I want it to run for all months not just for the current date or month. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional information from the below comments, change the following line:

```
$searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_4d WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_result, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m');";
```

to

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['month'] ) && is_numeric( $_REQUEST['month'] ) && intval( $_REQUEST['month'] ) > 0 && intval( $_REQUEST['month'] ) < 13 ){
    $searchMonthInt = intval( $_REQUEST['month'] );
    $searchMonth = "$searchMonthInt";
}else{
    $searchMonth = "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m')";
}
$searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_4d WHERE DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date_result, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%m') = $searchMonth";
```

Comment: because in that code, it runs only for a current date , like now, december, the program display only that has 12/**/2015,if have in database, because it formated as december, when i use my drop down to select other month, the program not runs. and stays only for that current month

Comment: Could you give us more of the relevant code? I don't see any code having to do with the drop down or how it is submitting to this page. I'm guessing the solution will be to modify the same line I mentioned, but to show the month you selected instead of `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m');`

Comment: I understand that part, but you seem to be saying that this should be somehow linked to a drop down. I do not see any code creating the drop down menu, showing the form it uses to submit, or the queries this page is receiving in order to somehow link the drop down to this query. [working link to database screenshot](http://prntscr.com/9eme1k)

Comment: so thats, why sir i need help on this part.. maybe the else ?

Comment: So you do not yet have a drop down menu yet? In that case, you will need to create an HTML form somewhere (I can't say where without seeing more code), create the drop down menu(s) and a submit button in the form, and then modify the line I mention earlier to use the values submitted from that form to create the date string to be used in the comparison instead of `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m');`.